# Okay to run sp_refreshview against all views on a regular basis?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, metadata

Microsoft SQL Server has a system stored procedure called [sp_refreshview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-refreshview-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) which updates the metadata of the view that's passed in.

Are there any downsides to running this procedure regularly on all of my views? (Such as performance statistics being affected, etc?)

Could I run it nightly, hourly, every few minutes?

If there's no repercussions in doing so, it seems like a good way to ensure my views metadata stays up to date when there's potential for the underlying entities they reference to change.

Comment: Even if you could run it on a schedule, there is no need to do so. At worst, you could create a DB trigger on object changes, and use the code in the second example on the linked page to update only those items with changed underlying objects.

Comment: So you recommend a DB trigger over something like a scheduled job, if it were possible? (Thinking pseudo-ly, I believe I could probably get what entities have changed since the last scheduled run, and then get their dependent entities, so that I only refreshed those entities.)
Is the primary reason you recommend a DB trigger is because the metadata management would be real-time then?

Comment: The main reason is related to how frequently your objects actually change. If you are changing tables, indexes, fields, etc. on existing objects frequently enough that a check every hour is somehow reasonable, then your process is very different than that anywhere I have worked before - and I'm 35 years in now. Your trigger might go off once every... what? Week?  And the number of views referencing the object won't be 100% in (almost) any case, so doing this for all views is wasteful of resources. The trigger ensures that the data is updated only for those items that need it when it happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> there's potential for the underlying entities they reference to change

This is the problem, and you should solve it at the source.

If you are updating objects in the database frequently enough that you have to automate frequent metadata corrections, there is probably an opportunity for better processes.

And you shouldn't be updating tables without also updating the views that reference them. So the views should become part of your schema modification workflow.

You can use `WITH SCHEMABINDING` on the views, which will explicitly enforce  that you can't modify referenced objects without knowingly removing the schema binding. (As an added bonus, your views can't use `SELECT *`, which is likely part of the problem here).

I wrote about this in the following article:

- [Benefits of `SCHEMABINDING`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4673/benefits-of-schemabinding-in-sql-server/)

Comment: The basis for my question was for two cases:

1) We have a significant number of entities in our primary database (a mix of different vendor application's entities via replication and our own internal application entities). Historically keeping track of what needed to be updated (and how many layers deep to go) has been problematic where occasionally we've missed dependent entities. (Though I realize this isn't an excuse to be a lazy developer, and I'm starting to realize maybe I can develop something to easily check the full stack of dependencies and make it part of our update process.)

Comment: 2) We are frequently loading data from other outside data sources which have the potential to change in structure somewhat frequently, and were possibly looking to leverage the sp_refreshview to help maintain our entities when this occurs.

Thanks for your answer. SCHEMABINDING doesn't sound too bad (I'm used to it for indexed views) but I have a feeling my developers might not like it based on the frequency we're making changes to our entities.

Comment: In most cases entity shift slows down over time. In any case, SCHEMABINDING could be the thing that (a) forces developers to queue up multiple changes at once and/or (b) weigh more heavily the impact of some of the changes, focusing on the ones that are important. It's still all "automatable" so I'm not sure how much this will actually impact the developer writing or using the views - if the view is changing because of a metadata change to the object(s) it references, that should be transparent to them.